# Categories with fixed choices design

Tags: design, object-oriented, python

I need to make a category/type class to identify an object. The usual way to do it is just pass a string to initialize a new category:

```
category = Category('A')
obj = Object(category)
```

However, the set of categories to use should be fixed. Nobody should be able to create a new category and use it in an object.

What design fits best this scenario?

A naive way of doing this can be the following:

```
class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CategoryFactory:
    categories = (Category('A'), Category('B'), Category('C'))
    category_dict = {c.name: c for c in categories}

    @staticmethod
    def get(name):
        return CategoryFactory.category_dict[name]

class Object:
    def __init__(self, category):
        if category not in CategoryFactory.categories:
            raise ValueError
        self.category = category

    def __str__(self):
        return "Object of category '%s'" % self.category

    __repr__ = __str__
```

That way I can instantiate an `Object` with a valid category:

```
valid_category = CategoryFactory.get('B')
# output: Object of category 'B'
Object(valid_category)
```

And act upon invalid categories:

```
invalid_category = Category('D')
# ValueError is produced
Object(invalid_category)
```

But I'm not really happy with this design. How is this scenario usually handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python really doesn't have good encapsulation mechanisms. You are left with three possibilities:

- Discourage private details from being used by prefixing their name with underscores.
- Discourage private functions from being called by requiring a “token” parameter.
- Use the strongest encapsulation mechanism available in Python: closures.

Naming is clear: who would instantiate a `_Category`? The name indicates that this class is an implementation detail and should not be used by external code. When you import all variables from a module via `from module import *`, names with leading underscores are skipped. Additionally, some static analysis tools (e.g. pylint) will warn you if you access such a name from another scope.

Sometimes you do want the class name to be public, but just want to prevent calls to the constructor. This might be the case if you need the name for `isinstance()` checks, or if you want to write documentation for the type. One technique I sometimes use is to require a private access token as a function parameter:

```
_PRIVATE_TOKEN = []  # any new reference will do

class OnlyPrivateInstantiation(object):
  def __init__(self, _token, ...):
    assert _token is _PRIVATE_TOKEN  # check for identity
    ...
  ...
```

Technically the private token might still be externally visible, but see above about naming.

If you don't want to rely on naming conventions like an underscore, you can put all private details into a closure that then returns all public objects. This technique is often used in JavaScript, but can also be used in Python with an extra line of code.

```
def _make_categories():

  class Category:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

  # init any data outside of the objects you return
  categories = (Category('A'), Category('B'), Category('C'))
  category_dict = {c.name: c for c in categories}

  class Categories:
    # implement expected collection methods as required
    def __iter__(self): return iter(categories)
    def __contains__(self, item): return item.name in category_dict
    def get(self, name): return category_dict[name]

  return Categories()

CATEGORIES = _make_categories()
```

Now this or a combination of the above features is going to be the best we can get with Python, but it's still fundamentally futile. Once we have an instance we have its class, and once we have a class we can create another instance: `type(category)("name")` or `category.__class__("name")`. And even outer variables can be accessed from a function thanks to rich reflection capabilities (at least under CPython): the `function.__closure__` tuple lets you access the value of every nonlocal variable used by that function. But whoever uses reflection features (no matter how convenient they may be) wilfully violates the normal contract around the involved objects, so trying to defend against that would be unnecessarily paranoid.